# How to assign textarea value in non-form using Symfony\DomCrawler?

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, silex

I am doing functional unit test for Silex based application.

I am able to select textarea nodes using:

```
use Silex\WebTestCase;

$textarea = $crawler->filter('[note-for="'.$cart->id.'"]');
```

This returns Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler Object.
I would like to assign value to this textarea. This textarea is not in a form tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the setValues() member function of the DomCrawler object:

> $form->setValues(array(
>       'element-id' => 'value' ));

The DomCrawler is covered in more detail [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html).

Answer (score 0):

From symphony [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html):

> An instance of the Crawler represents a set (SplObjectStorage) of
>   DOMElement objects, which are basically nodes that you can traverse
>   easily:

Simply use:

```
foreach($textareas as $textarea) {
  $textarea->nodeValue  = "TEST";
};
```